# Creating Associative Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a multidimensional array.

```
$shop = array( 
              array("appn1", "pub1" ,"pub2" , "pub3"),
              array("appn2", "pub1"),
              array("appn3", "pub1" ,"pub2")
            );
```

The first item in each array is **application number** and the rest in each array are the **publication numbers**. I get the first item(application number) and the last item of each array(latest publication number) like this

```
 $index = count(array_keys($shop));
    for($i=0;$i<$index;$i++){

        $appln_nr = $shop[$i][0];
        echo $appln_nr;

        $publn_nr_index = count(array_keys($shop[$i]))-1;
        $publn_nr = $shop[$i][$publn_nr_index];
        echo $publn_nr;
   }
```

Now I have application number and publication number for each inner array.

I want to create an associative array from the application numbers and publication numbers.

where the key should be the application number and its value is the publication number.

Thanks

**EDIT**

What I am getting from $shop array

```
 Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => appn1
        [1] => pub1
        [2] => pub2
        [3] => pub3
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => appn2
        [1] => pub1
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => appn3
        [1] => pub1
        [2] => pub2
    )
)
```

And this is what I need in my associative array

```
Array(
    "appn1" => "pub3"
    "appn2" => "pub1"
    "appn3" => "pub2"
)
```

Comment: How can I create the associative array from application and publication numbers?

Comment: Form the above array .. what is your expected output ....

Comment: @Baba Have a look at my Edit please

Comment: from what u defined, you have more than one pub_number in one app_number. do you want the value of each element to be an array of pub_numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i understood what you wanted, after your edit XD:

```
$shop = array(
    array("appn1", "pub1" ,"pub2" , "pub3"),
    array("appn2", "pub1"),
    array("appn3", "pub1" ,"pub2")
);
$shopNew = array();

foreach($shop as $value){
    $shopNew[$value[0]] = end($value);
}

// now if you want you can replace $shop and unset $shopNew
$shop = $shopNew;
unset($shopNew);    

print_r($shop);
```

the output is this:

```
Array (
  [appn1] => pub3
  [appn2] => pub1
  [appn3] => pub2
)
```

Comment: This is already I ma doing i want to change it now to associative array

Comment: @UmairIqbal it is an associative array. That's what's being shown except he's `var_dump`ed the result instead of `print_r`

Comment: I edited my answer because the question wasn't clear at first, @UmairIqbal 's comment is before the edit :P

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert your array into a new format by using the first element as key (see [`reset`](http://php.net/reset)) and the last element (see [`end`](http://php.net/end)) as value:

```
foreach($shop as $fl) {
    $v[reset($fl)] = end($fl);
}
```

Result is in `$v` then.

If you want to transform the array you need to delete each element as well:

```
foreach($shop as $v => $fl) {
    $shop[reset($fl)] = end($fl);
    unset($shop[$v]);
}
```

Result is in `$shop` then. Unset takes care of removing from the array.

Output in both cases is:

```
array(3) {
  'appn1' =>
  string(4) "pub3"
  'appn2' =>
  string(4) "pub1"
  'appn3' =>
  string(4) "pub2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$shop = array(
        array("appn1","pub1","pub2","pub3"),
        array("appn2","pub1"),
        array("appn3","pub1","pub2")
        );

$final = array();
array_map(function ($var) use(&$final) {$final[reset($var)] = end($var);}, $shop);
var_dump($final);
```

Output

```
array
  'appn1' => string 'pub3' (length=4)
  'appn2' => string 'pub1' (length=4)
  'appn3' => string 'pub2' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 foreach($shop as $k => $v) {            
     $new_arr[$v[0]] = end($v);      
 }
```

It should give you this result,

```
$new_arr = array(
      "appn1" => "pub3",
      "appn2" => "pub1",
      "appn3" => "pub2"-
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create like this,

```
$arrField = [];
$arrField['id'] = '0001';
$arrField["first_name"] ='Demo Test';
print_r($arrField);
```

print_r($arrField) display output like this.

```
Array ( [id] => 0001 [first_name] => Demo Test )
```