# encoding multidimensional array into json format

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
employees = [
    {
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe",
    "sub":[{"sub_name":"subcat1"},
           {"sub_name":"subcat2"}
    ]
    }, 
    {
    "firstName":"Anna",
    "lastName":"Smith",
    "sub":[{"sub_name":"subcat3"},
           {"sub_name":"subcat4"}
    },
    {
    "firstName":"Peter",
    "lastName":"Jones",
    "sub":[{"sub_name":"subcat5"},
           {"sub_name":"subcat6"}
    },
];
```

I want to construct a multidimensional array which after ecoding using json_encode() function in php should give me the output in above mentioned json format.

How the multidimensional array should look like?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: So, the problem is actually you don't know how to build your array in first place? Take a look at [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863259/creating-associative-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work backwards from the json you've got, run `var_export(json_decode($json, true))` and take a look at the array it gives you.